# How to surf the internet using static IP using SSL VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I have a Fortinet 60D device which configured to use SSL VPN this appliance connect to ADSL router with WAN interface and to my Radius server on LAN interface.

The problem is when I go out to the internet through SSL VPN my requests will come back to my real IP here in my house not to the ADSL real IP which connect to Fortigate.

Furthermore, I have configured the Fortigate to use dynamic IP pool but every time I connect to the SSL VPN I get the Fortigate wan address IP not the dynamic IP pool. And when I opened cmyip.com I found my real IP not the ADSL real IP which connect to the Fortigate.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the (professional) task you are trying to accomplish?  Is it that you want all your users' internet traffic to go over the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you mentioned your house, I'm guessing that was for testing and you are the netadmin from your comments.

> The problem is when i go out to the internet through SSL VPN my
>   requests will come back to my real IP here in my house not to the ADSL
>   real IP which connect to fortigate.

That part actually makes it sound like you have split-tunneling enabled.  Disable split-tunneling and possibly make sure that any other route settings are already correct, and then all ssl vpn traffic should flow through the Fortinet and out the ADSL router at the office.  Check the split-tunneling settings in the Fortinet to disable it and force traffic through the SSL VPN itself and not just traffic bound for your LAN.

> furthermore, i have configured the fortigate to use dynamic ip pool
>   but every time i connect to the ssl vpn i get the fortigate wan
>   address ip not the dynamic ip pool. and when i opened cmyip.com i
>   found my real ip not the ADSL real ip which connect to the fortigate.
>   ????????

I think that's still related to split-tunneling.  Again, disable it and then test again.